# How to measure sound frequency using microphone gy-max4466?

Tags: c++, arduino, iot, nodemcu

I have a project that uses sound sensors. but the output is not in frequency units. how do I make the coding so that the output is in the form of frequency (hz). I used the Arduino IDE to code it. thanks for your attention

Comment: Have a look at the FFT

Comment: please do a websearch prior to asking questions here. arduino audio processing, arduino audio frequency, arduino audio spectrum. you'll get plenty of answers and solutions. building aduio spectrum analysers is a very very common diy project

Comment: When learning to program, it helps to break down your problems. Could you do it on a regular computer? No? Then the Arduino isn't your first problem.

Comment: If you're interested in the fundamental frequency, you could use a [pitch detection algorithm](https://www.google.com/search?q=pitch+detection+algorithm)

Answer (score 2):

In order to get the spectrum of an audio signal you have to transform it from time domain to frequency domain. This is usually done with the Fast Fourier Transform (FFT).

https://www.rationalacoustics.com/files/FFT_Fundamentals.pdf

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_Fourier_transform

This is a very common thing in the Arduino community. Websearch will overwhelm you with tutorials and other resources.

Comment: A good startng project for arduino fft: https://learn.adafruit.com/piccolo/code

Also from me the best starting point on understanding FFT: http://www.dspguide.com/ch18.htm